Can I create a Shortcut for Hot Reload -> "Restart Application"
I would like to create a Command Bar Button or Shortcut for:

Note this is not the same as:

I prefer a Command Bar button but I couldn't find it in the Add Command Button under Debug.  Perhaps it's in another Menu?  If there is no Command Bar Button is there a Shortcut?


I think there is no  similar Debug.HotReloadRestart feature in Commands box. You can raise a feature request from here


Can I create a Shortcut for Hot Reload -> "Restart Application"

No, i think it's a new feature. No similar Debug.RestartApplication in Commands box is available.
During my investigation, i enable VSIPLogging in the registry and  set the EnableVSIPLogging to 1 to get the Guid and Canonical name of Restart and Restart Applicaton.

It seems Restart Application has not been set Canonical name. Therefore，i would suggest you raise a feature request at Visual Studio Forum
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Thank you Dou!  I appreciate your response

My pleasure. If you have submitted a feature request, please share the link with us for better tracking.

I've never created a feature request.  I just started using VS two months ago but I will learn.

Sure, you can raise it from here.

Here is the feature request link Dou. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Please-allow-for-Visual-Studio-HotReload/10752133
